Why would text be corrupted in various editors when scrolling with mouse wheel (rapidly)
I have a problem where rapid scrolling up and down of text in various editors (both VS Code and Eclipse for sure) causes fragments of text from elsewhere.
I had attributed this to bit-rot in my install of 22.04 so took the opportunity to replace with a fresh install of 24.04 however the problem is still very much present.
I wouldn't imagine this is a graphics problem which would probably not impact the content of the editor buffer.  I can't even work out where the text is coming from, sometimes it is obviously content from elsewhere in the file, sometimes it is completely random.  I have wondered if it was from the clipboard buffer but it doesn't seem to be.
In the capture below you can see where rapid scrolling has ended up with the word "VSCode" blatted into the source in a couple of spots, this was definitely not part of the source file but was text that I highlighted and changed while writing the post.

I'll keep digging but just throwing this out to see if anybody else has seen this particular glitch.
Frustrating because sometimes I don't notice it and have to undo back through a load of code changes or try and work out manually how to fix up the mess.
Cheers.

ANSWER: Turns out this is actually the middle-paste operation of the mouse being super responsive (doh) and the text is coming from the clip-board.
I guess the solution is to disable this function, the paste on middle button is a feature from the desktop.
Gtk has a config option to disable:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste false
And for those that want to disable it just in VS Code:
set the "editor.selectionClipboard": false. This disables vs code's integration with the Gnome desktop primary paste function.
This is a new mouse and I should have thought of that as the obvious.
